# How to turn *argv[] into a string inside isaplha

Tags: c++, argv

New to programming C++ and am having an issue with using isaplha to recongnize and display an error message when an argument is a letter. A, A1, and any combination of alpha-numerals starting with a letter displays an error, how ever 1a will pass as containing no letters. My code is as follows.

```
for(int s = 1; s< argc; s++)
{
    if (isalpha(*argv[s]))
    {
        cout << "You have entered a letter, however letters are not valid arguments";
    }
    else etc... etc...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you need the * before argv, you can just do isalpha(argv[s]) I think...

Comment: I don't understand what your expected behaviour is, exactly - do you want to treat any string containing a letter (uppercase or lowercase) to yield an error message?

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the char-array. What happens now is that you take the n-th argument (`argv[s]`) and dereference that (pointer to the first character of the n-th argument).

Comment: *argv[s] is the first character of the argument, so you're not checking subsequent letters at all.

Comment: @Welshboy `argv[s]` is a char array. `*argv[s]` is a char. You can't check `isalpha` on an array.

Comment: @zenith ah, I stand corrected, thanks for the correction.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `argv` is an array containing C-strings, `argv[s]` is a C-string, and `*argv[s]` (which is equal to `argv[s][0]`) accesses only the *first* character in that string.

If you want to check that there are no letters in the entire char array, you'll have to loop through that array too:

```
for(int s = 1; s < argc; s++) // loops through the array of C-strings 
{
    for(int c = 0; c < strlen(argv[s]); c++) // loops through each C-string
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[s][c]))
        {
            cout << "You have entered a letter, however letters are not valid arguments";
```

Comment: Do you mean strlen(argv[s])?

Comment: Yeah I fixed that one ages ago ;)

Comment: @Sam Bianco At least do `if (std::any_of(argv[s], argv[s]+strlen(argv[s]), isalpha))`. There is a movement these days not to write your own loops whenever possible. Using std algorithms reads better, like english "if any of the [chars in a string] are alpha". That said, use my answer instead, below.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Store args in a vector of strings for ease of use (excluding first arg)
auto args = std::vector<std::string>{argv+1, argv+argc};

// Iterate through each argument
for(auto& arg : args)
{
    // If any of the characters in arg (a string) are alpha
    if(std::any_of(arg.begin(), arg.end(), std::isalpha))
        /*...*/
    else
        /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into pieces.

`argv[1]` is the first command-line parameter.
(`argv[2]` is the second, and so on...)

It has a length, determined by `strlen`.
Iterate over that length, checking each character:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* Param1 = argv[1];

    for(int s = 0; s< strlen(Param1); s++)
    {
        if (isalpha(Param1[s]))
        {
            cout << "You have entered a letter, however letters are not valid arguments";
```